# add a vertical line on an excel chart

Tags: excel

I have a line chart in excel with data already set; I need to add a vertical line that moves according to the X values (month dates). For example for this month the line will move on the X value of "Jul-20"

Below I have attached the screenshot of the chart and the chart data. I have never had my hands on excel chart up until now and this chart has not been made by myself. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Chart]

[image: Chart data]

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to @Steven Pomponio

when I try to add the new series for the vertical line, I do not have the "Y" values; see screenshot

**UPDATE 2**

added a new data source with values as 01/072020 and /01/07/2020 in cells J182 and K182; now I see a black dot  on the left between the £10.0m and £ 20.0m Y values. If I change the verttical line data source chart type to be "Scatter with straight lines" then I do not even see the point.
If I change teh entire chart to be of `Scatter with straight lines` then I do see the  `Series Y Values` but the whole chart change design and I do not want to do this.

[image]

[image: Vertical line data series]

[image: Chart Type]

**UPDATE 3**
Thanks to @Steven Pomponio  I did it
[image]

Comment: Perfect, so the main change you'll want to do is find the `Vertical Line Series` within the bottom box selection and change the `Chart Type` drop down box to `Scatter with Straight Lines`. From there, you might need to go back to `Select Data` and chose to Vertical Line -> `Edit`, where you should now see the two separate `Series X Values` and `Series Y Values`.

Comment: **Per UPDATE 2**: After you change the chart type to `Scatter with Straight Lines` it is okay if the data "disappears" from the view. This is most likely caused by the fact that when you set change the chart type the `Series Y Values` are missing from the data series. Once you go back to `Select Data` and edit the vertical line it should appear properly.

Comment: Sorry Steven, I was looking at vthe bottom of the page and not seeing these comments. i did it tanks to you. See Update 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose two cells in which you will have your target x value where the vertical line will appear, for this example I'll be using cells (E1) and (E2). Within cell (E1) you'll want to type in the formula `=TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())+1` in order to get the first date of the current month. Cell (E2) can just be `=E1`.

In two cells, preferably next to them you will need to enter in the **minimum** and **maximum bounds** of one of your axes (*Since you are already using a dual axes*). It is important that these numbers are the same as what you set for the axis min & max bounds as this allows for you the line to properly span across the entire chart. **Don't leave them on** `Auto`.

Next, right click on your chart and click `Select Data` -> `Add` -> and add in the two dates (*cells (E1) and (E2)*) into the `Series X Values`, and the min and max bounds into the `Series Y Values`.

The final step is to make sure that the Chart type for this newly added series is selected as `Scatter with Straight Lines` and plotted on whichever axis you set the bounds equal to.

Comment: Hi Steven, many thanks; as I said this is my first chart ever and I have two questions:
1) where do i find the  minimum and maximum bounds values? 
2) How I change teh chart type only for the newly added series?

Comment: To answer your first question pertaining to the minimum and maximum bound values, you can find it by right clicking on your chart axis and selecting `Format Axis`, and then navigating the pane to `Axis Options` where you should be able to modify the bounds. Once these are changed they will become static and no longer change automatically if new data is added that extends past these points, so bear that in mind. As for your second point, I want to confirm that your initial chart is indeed set to `Combo` which you can find by again right clicking the chart and selecting `Change Chart Type`.

Comment: Perfect, so by default you should notice that next to the values is `Auto` when you manually change them (*even if you type the original numbers*) it will change from `Auto` to a clickable `Reset` that sets it back to `Auto`. You want to make sure you update these two numbers so that `Auto` is no longer displayed and then copy the corresponding values into the two cells you are using for the `Series Y Values`.

Comment: see my "updates" writing it now...  and many many thanks for helping me with this. and yes the chart is "combo"

Comment: I added the line but is a sigle black dot between the £10.0 and £20.0 Y left values; if I change the chart type to be Scatter with Straight Lines then I cannot even see the black dot; see update 2 in my question